# Looking for general advice/guidelines on deriving a probability density function for waiting times for a queue

Tags: distributions, queueing

So I'm a student in my final year of high school, and the course that I take (IBDP) requires us to write a 12-20 page 'mathematical exploration' on a topic of our choosing. I am interested in deriving a probability density function of waiting times for the queue in my school cafeteria. I have read up on some of the preliminaries of queueing theory, but I have gotten lost whenever I try to read papers that actually model something similar to my topic.

I would just like to get some advice on the feasibility of my topic - if it is possible for my current education level (I am willing to do some self-study), and, if so, if anyone could give me some general pointers as to how I could approach my topic, as well as some resources that explain this stuff in more detail.

Thanks so much guys

Comment: The reader cannot guess which degree of complexity, completeness or accuracy you can manage. Maybe try looking at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPfKo_Pq6vg

Comment: @Carl Hi! Thank you so much for the video, I would like to get something similar to that. I understand that arrival rates of the queue can be modelled by the Poisson distribution, and service rates by the exponential distribution. What I would like to do (if possible) is derive a PDF from these two distributions that allows me to see the corresponding probability for any amount of waiting time in the system (time queueing for service + receiving service). I am just not sure how to exactly go about doing this. I only know Little's Law, but that only allows me to calculate average waiting time.

Comment: Maybe try a search on DuckDuckGo of *derivation of wait time formulas*. Read the basics. If some treatments are too hard, try other ones.

Comment: Normally, in real-world problems like this it is not possible to "derive" a distribution that describes a phenomenon: one *observes* the phenomenon and *describes* it quantitatively.  Consider, then, actually measuring waiting times.  If later you wish somehow to model them, these observations will be crucial for selecting appropriate forms of a model.

Comment: I know it sounds terse, and possibly trite, but you need to keep learning the required mathematics to even have a hope of solving some of these problems. Practitioners like myself do not spend most our time deriving formulas, rather we develop and validate models, but we appreciate mathematical results when they are available. 